# Is there a way to make IE7 default to ms-image-mode:bicubic?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

Internet Explorer 7 uses a rather crude method to resize images by default. There's a CSS tag `img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }` to get better results, but I'm unable to change the source of the page. IE8 uses the better method as the default, but this is a corporate environment that is unable to upgrade at this moment.

Is there anything in the options or a registry hack to change the default resizing mode in IE7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that into a CSS file somewhere and set it as an [user style](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/ht/htcssuseriewin.htm).

Comment: Never did get this to work, but they finally upgraded to IE 8 so it's a moot point. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can put that rule in a user CSS file and perhaps you can set that via group policies.